# What is the behavior of these linkers?

Tags: c, linker, segmentation-fault

From this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6768/shortest-code-that-return-sigsegv-among-the-given-languages), I've seen a funny code which compile (although with warnings) and produce a segmentation fault (gcc 4.4.4; clang 2.8):

```
main;
```

If we expand it, here is the result:

```
int main = 0;
```

So what is the linker's behavior here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linker's behavior is that it defines a symbol called `main` in either the program's data or BSS segment.  It is 4 bytes long and initialized to 0.  Ordinarily, it creates a symbol in the program's code segment (typically called `.text`) with the executable code for the `main` function.

The C runtime starts up at a fixed entry point (typically called `_start`), initializes a bunch of stuff (e.g. sets up the program's arguments), and calls the `main` function.  When `main` is executable code, this is all fine and dandy, but if it's instead 4 zero bytes, the program will transfer control to those zero bytes and try to execute them.

Typically, the data and BSS segments are marked as non-executable, so when you try to execute code there, the processor will raise an exception, which the OS will interpret and then terminate your program with a signal.  If somehow the segment it's in is executable, then it will try to execute the machine instructions defined by `00 00 00 00`.  In x86 and x86-64, that's an illegal instruction, so you'd also get a `SIGILL` signal in POSIX OSes.

Comment: So, rather than `int main` can I do a `char main` and expect the same result?

Comment: @noMAD: Yep, if you define `main` as any global object, the same result will happen, unless you just happen to be running an OS that has an executable data segment (unlikely) and you initialize it to data that becomes valid executable code on your CPU (e.g. `char main = 0xC3` for a single `RET` instruction on x86).

Comment: @noMAD I get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol `main` is expected to be a function, not an integer.  However, the linker doesn't much care about the type of `main`; the symbol is defined.  If the symbol `main` is not a function with one of the prescribed signatures, then you invoke undefined behaviour.

The start-up code then calls the 'function', which is actually an address in the data segment of the program.  It goes wrong because the 'code' stored at that address is invalid — the first 4 bytes are likely to be zeros; what comes later is anyone's guess.  The data segment may be marked non-executable, in which case trying to execute the data will trigger a crash on that account.

When you invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen.  A crash is quite sensible here.

Comment: So, rather than int main can I do a char main and expect the same result?

Comment: To a first approximation, you'd get the same result regardless of the type of the variable `main` — `char`, `double`, `struct { a char[300]; }`, ...

Answer (score 3):

Under my system (CentOS 6.3), main is placed into the BSS and contains all 0's, hence the crash:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000006007f0 in main ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000006007f0 in main ()
(gdb) l
"main" is not a function
(gdb) disass 0x6007f0
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x00000000006007f0 <+0>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000006007f2 <+2>: add    %al,(%rax)
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) info symbol &main
main in section .bss of /home/ajd/tmp/x
(gdb) x/16b 0x6007f0
0x6007f0 <main>:    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x6007f8:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
(gdb)
```